# Drag-Drop item from one data group to another data group in Telerik RadListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am trying to use the Telerik RadListView Drag-Drop feature: 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/datagrouping/defaultcs.aspx

The code below works fine but loops through all the items to find the "e.DestinationHtmlElement" which is not efficient. I want to be able to drag an item from one data group to another data group for Telerik RadListView with a better algorithm. How can I do that?

**ASPX Code:**

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server" ID="Lsv_Vis" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50"
    ItemPlaceholderID="Phi_Vis_I" GroupPlaceholderID="Phi_Vis_G"
    DataKeyNames="url_id, lst_id, url_name, url_address" 
    ClientDataKeyNames="url_id, lst_id,     url_name, url_address"
    OnItemDrop="CsVisItemDrop" OnItemDataBound="CsVisIDB" DataSourceID="Sql_Vis">
</telerik:RadListView>

<DataGroups>
    <telerik:ListViewDataGroup GroupField="lst_id" DataGroupPlaceholderID="Phi_Vis_G">
        <DataGroupTemplate>
            <div class="Div_Vis_Grp"><span class="Spn_Vis"><%# (Container as RadListViewDataGroupItem).AggregatesValues["lst_name"].ToString() %></span></div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_Vis" runat="server" CssClass="Pnl_Vis" ToolTip='<%# (Container as RadListViewDataGroupItem).DataGroupKey %>' onmouseover='this.className += " Vis_Sel";' onmouseout='this.className = this.className.split(" Vis_Sel").join("");'>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Phi_Vis_I" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </DataGroupTemplate>
        <GroupAggregates>
            <telerik:ListViewDataGroupAggregate Aggregate="Max" DataField="lst_name" />
        </GroupAggregates>
    </telerik:ListViewDataGroup>
</DataGroups>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="Div_Vis_Item rlvI">
    <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_Vis" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("lst_id") %>' CssClass="Div_Vis_Item" onmouseover='this.className += " Vis_Sel";' onmouseout='this.className = this.className.split(" Vis_Sel").join("");'>
        <a class="Hyp_Vis" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("url_address") %>' target="_blank">
            <div class="Div_Vis_Body">
                <div class="Div_Vis_Con">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Div_Vis_Con" runat="server" class="Div_Vis_Con" ToolTip='<%# Eval("lst_id") %>' ></asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Div_Vis_Link">
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_VisI" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("url_name_short") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("url_name") %>'/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void CsVisItemDrop (object sender, RadListViewItemDragDropEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DestinationHtmlElement.IndexOf("Div_Vis_Con") < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (RadListViewDataItem di in Lsv_Vis.Items)
    {
        Panel pnl = di.FindControl("Div_Vis_Con") as Panel;

        if (pnl != null && pnl.ClientID == e.DestinationHtmlElement)
        {
            string uid = e.DraggedItem.GetDataKeyValue("url_id").ToString();
            string lid = pnl.ToolTip.ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con_Str"].ToString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [MyTable] SET lst_id = @lst_id WHERE url_id = @url_id", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lst_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lid;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@url_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uid;
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Lsv_Vis.Rebind();
}
```